# from a stack a number of options as 1,2,3 is given by user and we need to perform operations as specified

Tags: java

Question is:
You have an empty sequence, and you will be given N queries. Each query is one of these three types:

1. Push the element x into the stack.
2. Delete the element present at the top of the stack.
3. Print the maximum element in the stack.

I am not able to identify error in my code could anyone please help..

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Node {

  int data;
  Node next;

  public Node(int data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

public class Solution {

  public Node head;

  public void push(int data) //insert at begin 
  {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
  }

  public void pop() //deletion at begin
  {
    if (head == null) {
      System.out.print("stack underFlow");
      return;
    }
    head = head.next;
  }

  public int maxele(Node head) {
    Node max = head;
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null) {
      if (max.data > temp.data)
        max = temp;
      temp = temp.next;
    }
    return max.data;
  }

  public void display() {
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null) {
      System.out.print(temp.data + "");
      temp = temp.next;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Solution obj = new Solution();
    int maximumElement;
    int N, i = 0;
    int test;

    N = sc.nextInt();
    while (i < N) {
      test = sc.nextInt();
      if (test == 1) {
        obj.push(sc.nextInt());
      } else if (test == 2) {
        obj.pop();
      } else if (test == 3) {
        maximumElement = obj.maxele(obj.head);
        System.out.println(maximumElement);
        System.out.println();
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

```
//input is:
10     //here 10 is number of test cases
1 97   //here 1 means push
2      //here 2 means pop
1 20
2
1 26
1 20
2
3     //3 means Print the maximum element in the stack
1 91
3

//my code gives output as:
26
26
```

Comment: What output where you expecting to see instead?  What's actually wrong here?

Comment: I ***think*** `if(max.data>temp.data)` should be `if (max.data < temp.data)`

Comment: I would suggest using a `switch` instead of `if-else-if` and maybe an `enum` to translate the numeric value into a named instance. Each enum have an index, so you can easily transform `1` into `PUSH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not explain exactly what the problem was, nor what you expected. However, I'm guessing that your problem is that the "getMaximum" routine did not return the largest value in the stack.

Assuming *that* is the problem, the following version of the code should do what you expect.

Apart from changing the class name, putting it in a package and enabling function 4 (display the stack) and some minor formatting the program is the same - except for the test in the "getMaximum" routine. I've added some comments there explaining how your original line should be read and how my variant of it should be read.

Of course you could have also used `if (max.data < temp.data)` if you prefer to read it that way. I personally do not like it that way (I like to compare my data to my tracked value), but 50% of the population do like it that way, so who am I to argue!

```java
package stackexercise;

import java.util.*;

class Node {
  int data;
  Node next;

  public Node(int data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

public class StackExercise {

  public Node head;

  public void push(int data) //insert at begin 
  {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
  }

  public Node pop() //deletion at begin
  {
    if (head == null) {
      System.out.print("stack underFlow");
      return null;
    }
    Node x = head;
    head = head.next;
    return x;
  }

  public int maxele(Node head) {
    Node max = head;
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null) {
        // My guess is that this is what is wrong.
        // This calculates minimum value (not the max).
        // Read it as:
        //  If the number we are tracking is bigger than the
        //  current data element(i.e. current element is smaller),
        //  capture this (smaller) data element as the new value.
      //if (max.data > temp.data)
        // Whereas this can be read as:
        //  If this data element is bigger than the value we are tracking
        //  capture this (bigger) data element as the new value.
      if (temp.data > max.data)
        max = temp;
      temp = temp.next;
    }
    return max.data;
  }

  public void display() {
    System.out.println("Stack contents:");
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null) {
      System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
      temp = temp.next;
    }
      System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    StackExercise obj = new StackExercise();
    int maximumElement;
    int N, i = 0;
    int test;

    N = sc.nextInt();
    while (i < N) {
      test = sc.nextInt();
      if (test == 1) {
        obj.push(sc.nextInt());
      } else if (test == 2) {
          Node x = obj.pop();
          if (x != null) {
              System.out.printf("popped: %d\n", x.data);
          } else {
              System.out.println("Stack empty");
          }
      } else if (test == 3) {
        maximumElement = obj.maxele(obj.head);
        System.out.println(maximumElement);
        System.out.println();
      } else if (test == 4) {
          obj.display();
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a run (with two extra steps to display the current stack):

```
12 
1 97 
2 
1 20 
2 
1 26 
1 20 
2 
4 
3 
1 91 
4 
3 

popped: 97
popped: 20
popped: 20
Stack contents:
26 
26

Stack contents:
91 26 
91
```

BTW, did you know that Java already has a Stack class? It does all of the basic things you need a stack to do (push, pop etc). Believe it or not, the class is called Stack. Here is the [java version 8 javadoc for Stack class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).